# Como enviar o meu form junto com outra variável via POST do AJAX para o PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Então, tenho um formulário e envio os dados dele para um arquivo PHP via AJAX. 
Estou conseguindo fazer isso normalmente.

Só que agora tive a necessidade de enviar junto com o form, mais uma variável JavaScript do AJAX para o PHP. Para utilizar o valor dessa variável como condição no PHP.

Parece ser uma coisa bem simples, porém só estou vendo soluções mirabolantes na web . Se vocês puderem me ajudar, eu ficaria grato.

Segue abaixo o meu código JavaScript e uma parte do Código PHP:

```js
$('#resultados-pendentes').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formularioPendente = $("#formulario-consulta");
    var pendente = "PENDENTE";

    var retorno = inserirFormulario(formularioPendente, pendente);

}); 

   

function inserirFormulario(dados, condicao) {
    $.ajax({
        //dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: dados.serialize(), //Aqui eu gostaria de enviar minha variável
        url: "banco/pagina-minhas-tarefas/interface-resultado-pesquisa.php",
        cache: false,

    });
}
```

```html
<?php

 <!-- Arquivo PHP QUE RECEBE OS DADOS DO FORMULÁRIO (SÓ UMA PARTE DO CÓDIGO) -->

  <?php 

 require_once("../conexao/conexao-com-banco.php"); // CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO AO BANCO

 
  
 // CONSULTA GERAL DO BANCO  QUE RETORNA O RESULTADO DA CONSULTA DA PÁGINA INTERFACE.PHP 
  
 session_start(); 
 
   
   //PREENCHE AS VARIÁVEIS COM OS DADOS VINDOS DOS CAMPOS DO FORMULÁRIO
   $pegaropcao   = $_POST["prioridade"];
   $tipodedata = $_POST["data"];
   $dataInicial = !empty($_POST["dataInicial"]) ? $_POST["dataInicial"] : null;
   $dataFinal  = !empty($_POST["dataFinal"]) ? $_POST["dataFinal"] : null;
   $cod = $_POST["cod"];
   $empresas   = !empty($_POST["empresas"]) ? $_POST["empresas"] : "";
   $tributacao = !empty($_POST["tributacao"]) ? $_POST["tributacao"] : "";
   $atividade  = !empty($_POST["atividade"]) ? $_POST["atividade"] : "";
   
   
   $status = $_POST["status"];
   $responsavel = $_SESSION["nome"];


?>
```

Será que se eu só colocar o nome da variável ali depois da virgula onde estou enviando o formulário ela vai junto com o formulário ? (Digo, no data).

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que a **solução mais simples** seja continuar usando a facilidade que `serialize()` oferece num formulário, pode criar um `<input type="hidden" id="pendente" name="seu-name" >` e colocar a informação que precisa nele `$('#pendente').val(pendente)`, assim a função `serialize()` vai ler este campo.

> Um input do tipo `hidden` não aparece para o usuário.

Após colocar o `<input type="hidden" id="pendente" name="seu-name" >` dentro do seu formulário HTML basta alterar a seguinte parte do seu código:

```
$('#resultados-pendentes').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formularioPendente = $("#formulario-consulta");
    var pendente = "PENDENTE";
    $('#pendente').val(pendente); // Se esse valor da variável pendente vai mudar...
    var retorno = inserirFormulario(formularioPendente, pendente);

});
```

> Não esqueça de colocar o atributo `name` com o nome que seu código espera.

Comment: É o que eu faria também, o JS atualiza o campo `hidden`. Dessa maneira o envio do formulário ocorre sem interferência do JS.

Comment: Vale um voto então né? :D

Comment: Sim, mas essa opção do input type="hidden" não seria útil pra mim. Porque eu envio o formulário de outras formas além do submit. Por exemplo, tem uma <div> que quando clico nela, eu envio os dados do formulário também. e o valor desse input type="hidden" não poderia ser fixo.

Comment: Então não é apenas a adição de um campo, podem ser vários campos e de nomes diferentes?

Comment: Não vai ser fixo... você vai definir ele no JS... se ele depende de outro campo isso você vai definir no seu código.

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson, dentro de `$('#pendente').val(var)` **var** seria a sua variável.

Comment: @fernandosavio , eu só gostaria de ter uma variável que mandasse um valor para ser condição no arquivo php. Só que esse valor pode variar. Entende ? Laércio, estou analisando seu código e vendo como posso adaptá-lo ao meu.

Comment: Veja a resposta editada se ajuda.

Comment: @LaércioLopes , seu código me foi útil. Agora vou fazer umas adaptações aqui. Obrigado! Me serviu momentaneamente. O único porém é como eu enviaria, via AJAX, aquela variável "pendente" junto com o form para o arquivo PHP.

Comment: Valeu @ThiagoPetherson!

Comment: É exatamente isso que minha resposta está explicando, colocando o input dento do form HTML ele será lido pela função `serialize()`, basta colocar o atributo name correto e receber esse parâmetro no arquivo PHP. Exemplo HTML: `<input type="hidden" name="test" id="pendente">`  PHP: `$_POST['test']`

Answer (score 1):

Quando você usar jQuery e der um `serialize()` em um `form`, o que o jQuery está fazendo é transformando esse objeto em um *query parameters*, que é parecido com isso: `nome=Thiago&idade=99`.

Se você quer adicionar mais um parâmetro, é só concatenar ela na sua string mantendo o mesmo padrão: `&variavelExtra=texto-da-variavel`.

Você só precisa tomar cuidado com o *encode*, que você pode resolver com `encodeURIComponent()`.

O resultado final poderia ser algo assim:

```
dados.serialize() + '&variavel=' + encodeURIComponent(variavelComValor)
```

Comment: Thiago R, o '$variável' seria o que seria enviado via POST para o PHP ? Ou seja, no arquivo PHP, que recebe o que vem do AJAX, ficaria $_POTS['variavel'] ?

Comment: Não deu certo pra mim, Thiago R.

Comment: Como ta seu codigo nessa parte do envio?

Comment: Thiago R, consegui resolver momentaneamente com a solução do Laércio. Mas mesmo assim, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) para serializar o formulário e inserir novos dados antes de enviar por ajax ([exemplo de uso com ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)).

É importante checar a compatibilidade da funcionalidade se for usar FormData ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility), [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2)).

```js
let form = document.getElementById('form')

// Inicializa com os dados do Form
let formData = new FormData(form)

// Adiciona mais um valor aos dados
formData.append("campo4", "Valor 4")

$.ajax({
    url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
    type: 'post',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
}).then(response => console.log("- Dados enviados", response.form));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <input name="campo1" value="Valor 1">
  <input name="campo2" value="Valor 2">
  <input name="campo3" value="Valor 3">
</form>
```

Comment: Hoje tu me ajudou bastante